# What can we use instead of a model?

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller, separation-of-concerns

I have developed a simple Windows Forms application, which uses the MVC pattern as far as I can tell. I have done it successfully, but it raises a question: **What if the model changes, can you think how we might notify a view/controller of this event?**

What can we use instead of a Model? Is using delegates an answer?

Comment: don't understand your question...  if the model changes what do you want to do?  is this more a question about the view?  Are you wanting to do a postback on change or something?

Comment: Are you referring to ASP.Net MVC?

Comment: @tereško - You seem to be blindly mislabeling things again... This question has nothing to do with asp.net-mvc

Comment: A model can implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to notify someone (usually a view) of changes. You can use any variation of this functionality. The basic idea is to define an event in the model that is raised whenever something changes. You could define separate events for separate parts of the model.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619813/mvc-model-notifying-view-of-changes?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tracking changes inside a `Model`, you can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in that `Model` class. Then any change in the `Model` instance will be reflected in the binded instance. For example, if you bind the `IBindingList` of that `model` to a `DataGridView`, then the gridview will be automatically updated on any change of that `model`.